# angular 6 Error object is empty to handle exception

Tags: angular, http, exception, rxjs, angular6

I am trying to handle a unique constraint error in UI when an API errors out.

my service class as follows:

```
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

createArticle(ArticlePayload: any) {
    return this.http.post('/create', ArticlePayload, this.requestOptionHeaders).pipe(
    map(response => response.json()),
    catchError(err => this.errorHandler(err)));
}

public errorHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.log(' errorHandler =========> ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    return Observable.of(error);
}
```

My Component as below:

```
createArticle(payload: any) {
    this.myService.createArticle(payload).subscribe(
        response => {
            console.log(' response =>' + JSON.stringify(response));
            // something else
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(' FAILED =>' + JSON.stringify(error));
            this.notificationService.messageNotify('error', '', 'custom message needed here');
        }
    );
}
```

I am not able to get the error object in typescript as what I am seeing the network call.
[image]

console logs:

```
errorHandler => {}
response => {}
```

what i am missing. Can anyone help me out please?
i am using rxjs: "^6.2.2" version

Comment: By using `Observable.of` you're turning `error` notification into `next` notification so the error handler in your subscriber isn't invoked (you can use `Observable.throw` to throw another `error`). But I don't know if that's what you're asking...

Comment: martin is correct. You server-side is throwing an error, but the front end sees no error. It is dutifully logging the response object as it was commanded to do. 

Side note: if you want to lean into the JavaScript logger a little more, you can use `console.error(...)` instead of `console.log(...)` in your errorHandler() function.

Comment: I want the error response sent by server in errorHandler. I don’t want to throw any new exception and I also tried with console.error which resulted same as in console logs as mentioned above